# Problems setting up facebook screenshot-tests-for-android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to setup facebook’s [screenshot-tests-for-android](https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android) (v0.8.0) on our android app and I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create the directory /sdcard/screenshots/com.schibsted.peil.android.dev.test/screenshots-default for screenshots. Is your sdcard directory read-only?
at com.facebook.testing.screenshot.internal.ScreenshotDirectories.getSdcardDir(ScreenshotDirectories.java:121)
at com.facebook.testing.screenshot.internal.ScreenshotDirectories.get(ScreenshotDirectories.java:53)
at com.facebook.testing.screenshot.internal.AlbumImpl.<init>(AlbumImpl.java:44)
at com.facebook.testing.screenshot.internal.AlbumImpl.create(AlbumImpl.java:49)
at com.facebook.testing.screenshot.internal.ScreenshotImpl.create(ScreenshotImpl.java:66)
at com.facebook.testing.screenshot.internal.ScreenshotImpl.getInstance(ScreenshotImpl.java:84)
at com.facebook.testing.screenshot.Screenshot.snap(Screenshot.java:38)
at com.sample.myapp.ThirteenCardScreenshotTest.testScreenshot(ThirteenCardScreenshotTest.kt:24)
```

It seems something happens regarding the permissions to run the instrumented tests, on my apps `AndroidManifest.xml` I explicitly set the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission that the library needs, but it seems it’s not available on the instrumentation tests? or something else?

does anyone has experience with this library? any suggestions?

my test looks like:

```
package com.sample.myapp

import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry
import com.facebook.testing.screenshot.Screenshot
import com.facebook.testing.screenshot.ViewHelpers
import com.sample.myapp.feed.FooterStoryViewHolder
import org.junit.Test

class ThirteenCardScreenshotTest {
    @Test
    fun testScreenshot() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext

        val view = LinearLayout(context)
        val viewHolder = FooterStoryViewHolder(view)
        view.addView(viewHolder.itemView)

        ViewHelpers.setupView(view)
            .setExactWidthDp(360)
            .setExactHeightDp(740)
            .layout()

        Screenshot.snap(view)
            .record()
    }
}
```

And the workaround proposed in https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android/issues/162 doesn’t work for me

Comment: Also running into this issue - only on API 29 and higher.

Answer (score -1):

If you have debug environment for the app add this into its manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If not then u'll have to put it in the default app manifest

Comment: This is not the answer to the problem.